# Output is not what its supposed to be

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{   
    
        public class toy
        {
            string name = "";
            double price = 0;
            
            public string getName()
            {
                return name;
            }
            
            public double getPrice()
            {
                return price;
            }
            
            public void setName(string Name)
            {
                name = Name;
            }
            
            public void setPrice(double Price)
            {
                price = Price;
            }
            
            static void Main()
                
                
    {
            
            
            toy toy1 =new toy();
            toy1.setName("Car");
            toy1.setPrice(10);
            
            toy toy2 =new toy();
            toy2.setName("Soldier");
            toy2.setPrice(15);
            
            Console.WriteLine(toy1);
            Console.WriteLine(toy2);
                        
            
        }
    }
}
```

Hello, everyone. I am new at programming.
What did I do wrong here?
The output says
"Program+toy
Program+toy"

I wanted it to be like " Car 10
Soldier 15"

Comment: Hint: C# is case sensitive. I suspect you intended to override the `ToString` method, for which you'd need the `override` keyword.

Comment: I'd also suggest you learn about properties in C# (and C# naming conventions). At the moment this is C# with a *very* strong Java accent.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the following to your `toy` class:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{name} {price:0.00}";
}
```

Then you can do `Console.WriteLine(toy1);` and get what you want.  However, also follow Jon Skeet's advice!

### Explanation

The dollar sign at the start of the string stands for C#'s interpolated string feature, which allows you to insert variables into a string.  The curly braces then tell C# to insert a variable of that name into the string.

An alternative way of doing the same thing would be:

```cs
return string.Format("{0} {1:0.00}", name, price);
```

The '0.00' part tells C# how to format the number - in this case it will round the `double` to two decimal points, like a price would normally be.

Answer (score 2):

When you print `toy1` directly, you print the `object` not its name;
Already you define a cool method to get the toy name: `getName()`
So if you want to print the toy's name just call this method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(toy1.getName());
```

but if you want to print the toy name by calling the object name, you should override the `ToString()` method that runs whenever you behave your object like a string.
when you call `Console.WriteLine(SOMETHING_STRING)`, this method run `ToString()`

Let's redefine or override `ToString()` method in a way you expected before:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"The toy name is `{name}` and blah blah blah";
}
```

The final code is like:

```
public class Toy
{
        private string name;
        private double price;
        
        public string GetName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        
        public double GetPrice()
        {
            return this.price;
        }
        
        public void SetName(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public void SetPrice(double price)
        {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"The toy name is `{this.name}` and blah blah blah";
        }
```

}

I made some changes in your code to follow C# naming conventions. Please notice about changes. for more read this [article](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md)

## Welcome to C#

In the Csharp there is a built-in getter/setter method and unlike `Java` you do not have to define your setter method like `SetPrice()`.

As you did nothing special in the `SetPrice()` method, you can simply remove it and set the price like this: `toy1.Price = 1000;`  or get it like: `total_price += toy1.Price;`,
but if you want to validate user input or any other reason, In Csharp we do like this:

```
    private double price;
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0) // price shouldn't be negative
                price = value;
            else
                price = 0; // or throw execption

        }
    }
```

If I want to shrink your code it will be like:

```
public class Toy
{
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
    public double Price{ get; set; } 
    public override string ToString() => $"The toy name is `{this.Name}` and blah blah blah";
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but that's not following C# naming conventions just yet. Methods and properties use PascalCase, fields use camelCasing (or even a _ or m_ prefix)

Comment: I did some changes and update my answer @PMF

Answer (score 1):

You should pay special attention to Jon's suggestions. In addition, namespaces are important.

P.S. If you want the truth, I wouldn't answer such a sloppy question but even Jon is interested in it... Please pay more attention.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var toy1 = new Toy { Name = "Car", Price = 10 };
            var toy2 = new Toy { Name = "Soldier", Price = 15 };

            Console.Write(toy1);
            Console.Write(toy2);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }    

    class Toy {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public double Price { get; set; } = 0;//This is pointless because of its default value is already 0

        public override string ToString() => $" {Name} {Price}";
    }
}
```